# How to extract a particular string in java??

Tags: java, substring

My text file contains data and i am supposed to extract only ISDN string from it. The ISDN keeps on repeating and it's value keeps on changing too. The ouput i am getting is just 2 square brackets("[]") and there are not square brackets in the input file.

here is the input text file

```
CDR MOC={
   RecordType=0(MOC)
   sequenceNumber=5346435
   callingIMSI=40589345341354118911
   callingIMEI=80FC64634440F
   callingNumber{
      AddInd=H'134
      NumPlan=H'245
      ISDN=45645734
   }
```

here is my code

```
public class MyFile {

    private static final Pattern ISDN = Pattern.compile("ISDN=(.*)");

    public List<String> getISDNsFromFile(final String fileName)
            throws IOException {
        final Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
        final List<String> ret = new ArrayList<>();

        Matcher m;
        String line;

        try (
                final BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);) {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                m = ISDN.matcher(line);
                if (m.matches()) {
                    ret.add(m.group(1));
                }
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }

    public void writeTextFile(String filename, List<String> s) {
        FileWriter output = null;
        try {
            output = new FileWriter(filename);
            try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(output)) {
                String ss = String.valueOf(s);
                writer.append(ss);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            if (output != null) {
                try {
                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your line has white spaces at the beginning, and the regex thus doesn't match the line. You thus get an empty list as a result.

`trim()` the input before applying the regex, or use `\s*ISDN=(.*)` instead.

Comment: Finally manage to do it by using this regex \\s*ISDN=(.*). just one "\" was missing from your suggestion. Thanks for the help

Comment: The regex needs a single backslash. But backslashes must be escaped inside a String literal. If you read the regex from a file, for example, a single backslash would be needed.

Comment: With single backslash it gives me error that it is illegal regex but this thing works perfectly   private static final Pattern ISDN =Pattern.compile("\\s*ISDN=(.*)")

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use this regex:

```
ISDN=(\d+)
```

The Group 1 will contain the ISDN number.

In java, use this:

```
ISDN=(\\d+)
```

Code:

```
String s = "CDR MOC={" + "\r\n" +
"RecordType=0(MOC)" + "\r\n" +
"sequenceNumber=5346435" + "\r\n" +
"callingIMSI=40589345341354118911" + "\r\n" +
"callingIMEI=80FC64634440F" + "\r\n" +
"callingNumber{" + "\r\n" +
"AddInd=H'134" + "\r\n" +
"NumPlan=H'245" + "\r\n" +
"ISDN=45645734" + "\r\n" +
"}";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("ISDN=(\\d+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Demo:  http://ideone.com/KKUo56

Comment: you mean like this   private static final Pattern ISDN = Pattern.compile("ISDN=(\d+"); It is giving me error that it is malfunction regex

Comment: it is same output, just 2 square brackets nothing else

Comment: Finally manage to do it by using this regex \\s*ISDN=(.*). thanks for the help

Comment: My regex, will also, return the same. Check out the demo. It is working correctly

Comment: But problem is that there are total 20,000 lines including ISDN in the text file and i only need to extract ISDN so your method will not work with iniliation of sting